# How to publish multiple event using EventQueues.publish in zk

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, zk

Hope your problem is resolved, but my problem is still there
and I thought that you can help me to get out of this problem.
actually I had multiple events to publish one by one as per user
selection for eg: user select `Season`, `Service`, `DateFrom` and
`DateTo` and then clicks on the refresh button.

When the refresh button is clicked I had used the above logic to
get all the datas using the below mentioned code

```
public void onClick$ref(Event event){

    if(lbox_service.getSelectedIndex() != 0 || lbox_season.getSelectedIndex() != 0)
    {
        if(lbox_service.getSelectedIndex() == 0)
        {
            setService_id("0");
        }
        else
        {
            setService_id(lbox_service.getSelectedItem().getValue().toString());
        }
        if(lbox_season.getSelectedIndex() == 0)
        {
            setSeason_id("0");
        }
        else
        {
            setSeason_id(lbox_season.getSelectedItem().getValue().toString());
        }

        System.out.println("Service Index 11 : "+ lbox_service.getSelectedIndex());
        System.out.println("Season Index 11 : "+ lbox_season.getSelectedIndex());

        EventQueue evtQ = EventQueues.lookup("myEventQueue", EventQueues.APPLICATION, true);
        //evtQ.publish(new Event("service_id", self, lbox_service.getSelectedItem().getValue().toString()));
        //evtQ.publish(new Event("season_id", self, lbox_season.getSelectedItem().getValue().toString()));

        evtQ.publish(new Event("service_id", self, getService_id()));
        evtQ.publish(new Event("season_id", self, getSeason_id()));

        //evtQ.publish(new Event("onClickRef", null, lbox_service.getSelectedItem().getValue().toString()));
        //evtQ.publish(new Event("onClickRef", null, lbox_season.getSelectedItem().getValue().toString()));

        /*.publish(new Event("onClickRef", null, lbox_service.getSelectedItem().getValue().toString()));
         EventQueues.lookup("myEventQu", EventQueues.DESKTOP, true).publish(new Event(
             "onClickRef", null, lbox_season.getSelectedItem().getValue().toString()));*/
    }
    else
    {
        setService_id("0");
        setSeason_id("0");

        EventQueue evtQ = EventQueues.lookup("myEventQueue", EventQueues.APPLICATION, true);
        evtQ.publish(new Event("service_id", self, getService_id()));
        evtQ.publish(new Event("season_id", self, getSeason_id()));

        System.out.println("Service Index : "+ lbox_service.getSelectedIndex());
        System.out.println("Season Index : "+ lbox_season.getSelectedIndex());
    }
}
```

now i had publish all my value and after that my new `Controller`
run that will **subscribe** those published values. using the
below code

```
public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {

    super.doAfterCompose(comp);
    EventQueues.lookup("myEventQueue", EventQueues.APPLICATION, true).subscribe(new EventListener() {

        public void onEvent(Event event) throws Exception {

            /*String service = (String) event.getData();

            logger.info("Servive $$$$$$$$$ " + service);
            //String season = (String) event.getData();
            //logger.info("Season $$$$$$$$$ " + season); */     
            if("service_id".equals(event.getName())) {
                setService_id((String) event.getData());
                baseController.setFilter_bar(true);
                System.out.println("Service Id :" +event.getData());
            }
            else if("season_id".equals(event.getName())) {
                setSeason_id((String) event.getData());
                baseController.setFilter_bar(true);
                System.out.println("Season Id :" +event.getData());
            }

            /*setService_id((String) event.getData());
            setSeason_id((String) event.getData());*/

            /*if("season_id".equals(event.getName())){
                setSeason_id((String) event.getData());
            }else
            {
                setSeason_id("0");
            }*/
            System.out.println("Filter bar :" +baseController.isFilter_bar());
            if(baseController.isFilter_bar() == true)
            {
                String dateFrom = "";
                String dateTo = "";
                String order = "2";
                List TDRetailers = verificationStoreHibernateDao.getTraditionalRetailers(
                    getService_id(), getSeason_id(), dateFrom, dateTo, order);

                //VerificationStoreHibernateDao storeHibernateDao = new VerificationStoreHibernateDao();
                //List TDRetailers = this.verificationStoreHibernateDao.getTraditionalRetailers(service_id);
                //ListModel listModel = this.retailers.getModel();
                ListModelList listModelList = (ListModelList) retailer.getModel();
                listModelList.clear();
                listModelList.addAll(TDRetailers);
                baseController.setFilter_bar(true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

but actully my problem is with running the query and with
getting those published values. Based on them I will be able to
run my Traditional `getTraditionalRetailers` queries.

My problem is

1. how to publish multiple events values. Is it the right way
   that I had done.
2. as I had done separate publish, everytime
   **I publish new value The query runs**, the result is that i had
   mutiple time query execution. for example If i will publish two
   values the queries run's for the two times and if I publish
   three values the query executes for three time.

I don't know what is their problem. Help me to solve my error.

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

1. The event object passed through EventQueue is where you put your payload there. You can just define an aggregate Event class and collect information and publish them in a whole.
2. If you can publish all information in a whole(using an aggregate Event), this is solved automatically.